# can't save/update record using ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My Router defines the following:

```
this.resource('uoms', { path: '/uoms' }, function() {
    this.route('new');
});
```

And the `uoms` route is defined as:

```
App.UomsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('uom');
    },

    actions: {
        save: function() {
            this.modelFor('uoms').save().then(function() {
                console.log("saved UOMs");
            });
        }
    }
});
```

But for some reason when I try and save it I am getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'save'

Can someone help me identify what I'm doing wrong?

---- UPDATE ----

I also tried the following from the controller but with the same results:

```
App.UomsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions: {
        save: function() {
            this.get('model').save().then(function() {
                console.log("saved UOMs");
            });
        }
    }
});
```

---- UPDATE 2 ----

Looking at the object returned by the `this.get('model')` call we get the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I was running into was that I was trying to call `save()` on an array of records rather than a singular record. This problem was created because I was operating on a singular record but doing this within an `ArrayController`. I don't think there's anything wrong with this although it could be argued that I should have created a sub-route called "edit" and then presumably my code logic would have worked.

That said, if you want to do as I did (aka, save a singular record within an ArrayController) then this code will work:

```
save: function(id) {
    var promise = this.store.find('uom',id).then(function(uom){
        console.log(uom);
        uom.save();
    });
}
```

And then in the template put something like this:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk" {{action "save" id}}></span>
```

This works but is not the best answer. Instead you can specify in the `ArrayController` an `ObjectController` with the `itemController` property. Below is an example of both a `save()` and `deleteRecord()` handler using this strategy:

```
App.PluralController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    itemController: 'singular'
});

App.SingularController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        save: function() {
            this.get('model').save();
        },
        deleteRecord: function() {
            this.get('model').deleteRecord();
            this.get('model').save();
        }
    }
});
```

Then you'll want to do something like the following for your handlebars template:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk" {{action "save" this}}></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" {{action "deleteRecord" this}}></span>
```

Comment: Using `.destroyRecord()` will delete the record and save at the same time. [Ember docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/creating-and-deleting-records/)

Answer (score 2):

This is what I would do:

- Using Chrome Developer Tools set a breakpoint at the line where you try to save the model
- To inspect the model held by the controller enter `this.get('model')` the Chrome Developer Tools Console.

Check if the console output is really what you expect. Most probably it is not the model instance you want to save. You will see that you will get the same error when you execute `this.get('model').save()` in the console.

BTW: Why are you using an `ArrayController` and not an `ObjectController`. It looks like you use it for a single model. See the [docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/representing-a-single-model-with-objectcontroller/) for more details on that.

Edit:

Try `this.get('model').get('transaction').commit()`

Comment: Uoms is indeed an ArrayController of the model `Uom`. Why do you assume it is not?

Comment: I will try the debugging strategy you suggest and see what I get. Thanks.

Comment: To me it is not clear how your scenario looks: Do you display multiple  items in a template? Do you include a form within that template? Does the form allow to edit a single instance of UOM or even multiple items? What exactly is triggering the "save" action?

Comment: I have a list of UOMs and a user can click on one to edit it. Once they edit a record I want to persist that change back to the backend with a `save()`. I've updated the original question with the results from the `this.get('model')` call. It kind of looks like a reasonable object but as you can see from the new screenshot the error remains consistent.

Comment: I just noticed that I never use `save()`in my code. But `get('transaction').commit()` should do the trick. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I believe 'transactions' are now gone from the ember-data as of beta-1. Are you still using v0.13? Note: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

Comment: You're right, I am using ember-data 0.14, not 1.0, sorry for that.

Comment: How did you define your model? And can you access the model's properties at the breakpoint position like `this.get('model').get('myProperty')`?

Comment: I'm stumbling around a little but to answer your question `this.get('model').get('celcius')` where "celcius" is a UOM returns "undefined" but I do notice that `this.get('model').content` returns an array of objects which represent the various UOM records. So, for instance, `this.get('model').content[1]._data.id` is `celcius`. How about them apples?

Comment: Ok. I think I've solved the problem. It does all come down to your initial question about Array versus ObjectController. I'll write up the answer now. Thanks for all your help.